# Lua - gsub xml characters to make xml responses visible in iOS Safari Browser

Tags: ios, xml, lua, safari

For some reason the iOS Safari browser does not allow you to see xml content returned via a server.

So to try and get around this, I thought I’d try to take  the distinctive xml characters  ‘>’ and ‘<‘ with something else, which is unlikely to be challenged e.g ‘~’.

I’ve tried a number of different ways , and while I can use the following to find/replace letters, when I try it with special characters, i can’t seem to get it to work.

Can anyone help ?

```
local xmltest = "<XML Test>"
local t = {< = "~", > = "~"}
local result = string.gsub(xmltest, "<>", t)
print(result)
```

Many thanks

Comment: Your code does not compile.

Comment: Try `local t = {["<"] = "~", [">"] = "~"}; local result = string.gsub(xmltest, "[<>]", t)`.

Comment: Many thanks @lhf, i missed that when I went to special characters, I had to identify them differently

Answer (score 1):

Here is the answer, thanks @lhf

```
local xmltest = "<XML Test>"
local t = {["<"] = "~", [">"] = "~"}
local result = string.gsub(xmltest, "[<>]", t)
print(result)
```